# parallel reactor vs reactor Framework

Tags: poco-libraries, reactor

I have came across some networking framework when going through POCO C++ library.
Two of those are reactor and parallel reactor.

I would like to know what is the difference between these two framework.

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/poco-1.7.9/Net/include/Poco/Net/ParallelSocketAcceptor.h#L50):

> This is a multi-threaded version of SocketAcceptor, it differs from
>   the single-threaded version in number of reactors (defaulting to
>   number of processors) that can be specified at construction time and
>   is rotated in a round-robin fashion by event handler.